# (ngrx/store) How can I get the current state without subscribing, for use in a route Resolve?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, angular5

Currently I have very simple Resolve:

```
export class UserResolve implements Resolve<any>{

constructor(private userService: UserService){}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot){
        return this.userService.get(route.params.id);
    }
}
```

In the component, the user is then loaded into the store. What I'd like to know is how to get that user without having to subscribe to the Observable returned by the `select` function. The reason is because, if I navigate to the same url again, instead of sending another request so get the user info, I'd rather simply return the user from the store.

Basically, something like this is what I have in mind:

```
this.store.select(state => state.user)
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(user => 
            user.id == +route.paramMap.get('id') ? user : this.userService.get(route.params.id))
```

But I know this can't be done as you can't return anything within the subscribe function. Is it possible some other way though?

I know this could be somewhat achieved in the component, but I need it done in the Resolve, before the component is initialized.

I'm using Angular 5 and ngrx/store 4

Comment: You can use route guards (https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) and there check if the user is in the store. If not, retrieve from the API. In the component, always get from the store. This is a common solution/pattern in Angular's app with ngrx/store.

Comment: As far as I know, route guards are used to handle whether a user is allowed to navigate to a route or not. I don't see how this solves my problem. Could you give me an example with code?

Comment: The most common usage of route guards is that you mentioned, but you can do anything in a guard, when you need to do 'something' before a route is 'routed'. Take a look at this post: https://toddmotto.com/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards the user checks in the guard, inside the canActivate, if the user exists in the store or not.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common usage of route guards is that you mentioned, but you can do anything in a guard, when you need to do 'something' before a route is 'routed'. Take a look at [this post](https://toddmotto.com/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards): the user checks in the guard, inside the canActivate, if the user exists in the store or not